# Incluir sass em angular 5

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass

Qual melhor jeito de configurar o **SASS** no angular 5, e há alguma implementação especifica para organiza-lo no projeto.

Comment: com sugestão acabei chegando em uma solução, juntamente com essa pergunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220256/angular-cli-sass-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install node-sass`

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "node-sass": "node_modules/.bin/node-sass src/shared/css/style.scss -o src/shared/css/"
},
```

Aqui no caso eu tenho isso:

```
src/
  shared/
    style.scss
```

Quando eu executar no terminal:

`npm run node-sass`

Terei isso

```
src/
  shared/
    style.css   #gerado pelo node-sass
    style.scss
```

### sass-loader

`npm install sass-loader --save` 
**dica** instale em dependências de produção, se não da erro.

no seu webpack, faça isso:

```
model: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.(scss)|(css)/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'style-loader' #ÚLTIMO
        },
        {
          loader: 'css-loader'  #DEPOIS ESSE
        },
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader' #ESSE EXECUTA PRIMEIRO
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**sass-loader** transforma `sass` em `css`

**css-loader** transform `css` em `js`

**style-loader** transforma `csjs` em `css` de novo, porém agora ele pega tudo e insere em tags `<style>`